# Is there a counter for comments left?

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for a way to have a counter of "left comments" per user for all readers of my blog. ¿Is this possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_comments()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function to retrieve comments by `user_id` or you can modify the below to also accept `author_email` or multiple authors. It will then only return the Comment IDs as an array and count them up, returning the integer which could be 0.

```
/**
 * Count and return number of comments by User ID
 *
 * @param Integer $user_id - User ID of the wanted user
 *
 * @return Integer - Number of comments by given user
 */
function wpse284435_comment_count_by_author( $user_id ) {

    $user_id    = ( ! empty( $user_id ) ) ? intval( $user_id ) : get_current_user_id();
    $comments   = get_comments( array(
        'fields'    => 'ids',
        'user_id'   => $user_id,
    ) );

    return count( $comments );

}

$comment_count = wpse284435_comment_count_by_author( 7 );
```

Comment: thank you! is it possible to tweak your code so that it provides a list of number of comments for every user registered in the blog?

Comment: @EduardoPinto You can use [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to get all the users, loop through them and pass their ID into the above function to return their comment count.